# Custom htaccess in magento

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I want to make some custom htaccess rule for some page in magento.for this I have try to add some rewrite rule in htaccess file.but i always get 404 error.
ex.i want to rewrite http://www.mydomain.com/test/ to http://www.mydomain.com/varraible1/varraibe2/test/

please advise me some htaccess code for this.

thanks in advance

Comment: What Rewrite rules have you already tried?

Comment: can you please explain me the reason of downvoting??

Comment: I did not downvoted. But as long as you ask, your question doesn't look like you put enough effort to find a solution by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope URL rewrite works for you.

To enable the URL rewrite

Go to System > Configuration > Web > Search Engines Optimization and switch ‘Use Web Server Rewrites’ to Yes.

Check out the link below, to get detailed information on URL rewrite.

http://www.e-commercewebdesign.co.uk/blog/e-commerce-seo/htaccess-rewrites-for-magento-shops.php

Hope that helps